# Excel how to do Sigma Summation?

Tags: excel, statistics

I have data in cells
I know that I can do =Sum(B1:B15) to get the total but how would I do something like this [image: Ʃ(xi-x)]? I already have [image] calculated in another cell

For example, I tried doing something but I don't if it's right, plus I have the the thing using to different formulas and I get different answers [image]

this are the formulas I'm using
[image]

I tried doing something like this:
[image]

I'mm trying to do this one in that example:
[image]

but I don't think it is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For N=10 and the mean in cell **Y1**, try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((X1:X10-Y1)^2)
```

[image]